# Accepted width and height for Keras models

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have a dataset of rgb images of width and hight: 291x193

I am using several models like inception and effecientnet

Is it fine that I am using this dimension?? should dimensions be odd or ever or it does not matter?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged this under `keras` I will assume you are using the InceptionV3 function with `tf.keras`

The function has an optional shape tuple which can only be specified if `include_top` is `False` (otherwise the input shape has to be (299, 299, 3) following the `channels_last data` format or (3, 299, 299) with `channels_first` data format. It should have exactly 3 inputs channels, and width and height should be no smaller than 75. Also, you can specify the size only if `input_tensor` is not provided. You can add your required dimensions in the `input_shape` tuple.

Eg:

```py
tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=(100, 1000, 3),
    pooling=None,
    classes=1000,
    classifier_activation="softmax",
)
```

Comment: you are right I am using inceptionv3, am providing the size of the image in `input_tesnsor`.

Is it ok with 291x193dimensions?

Comment: Is it ok to use the `input_tensor` without the `input_shape` ??

Comment: Yes, a shape of `291x193` should be acceptable. You can only specify the `input_shape` if you have not specified the `input_tensor`. So as for your question, you can use `input_tensor` without the `input_shape`.